# Include header.jsp only for Logged in Users only

Tags: jsp, header, include

I have `index.jsp` , i need to include a `header.jsp` in that.The problem is - header.jsp contains dynamic menu (for loggedIn users and for non-loggedIn users) i can check if user is logged in or not using session in `index.jsp`. but not in `header.jsp`

How can i include header in this situation ??

Can i access session object in `header.jsp` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add conditional statement in `header.jsp`. (Presume that the you've session key named `islogged` that represent a *status* whether a user is logged or not)

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${not empty islogged}">
   //html markup for logged user
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
  //html markup for not logged user
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

EDIT :

@I don't have any session key maintained..but I would like to ..How can I do this?

Create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), compare username and password in doPost() method, set session key-value if user is *authenticated*.

You can verify a user (whether he/she is logged or not) by checking  a session key-value in [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

Comment: well, i don't have any session key maintained..but i would like to
..how can i do this..and to access user login status i need to know userId of the user who is logged in....how do i know that userId in header.jsp...

Answer (score 0):

you can put expression into header file, that checks you logged in condition.
For example.

```
<%
    if(user.session != null)
    {
      //includeFile here 
%>
      <jsp:include file="header.jsp" />
<%
    }
%>
```